# How better combine generic lists of different types inherited from one interfase?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, inheritance, union

I have interface:

```
public interface IBase
{
Guid Id { get; set; }
string ObjectName { get; set; }
string Val { get; set; }
}
```

and several classes that implement this inteface

```
public class A : IBase
{
Guid Id { get; set; }
string ObjectName { get; set; }
string Val { get; set; }
}

public class B:IBase
{
Guid Id { get; set; }
string ObjectName { get; set; }
string Val { get; set; }
}
```

also i have `DTO` class

```
public class CdcDto
{
 public List<A> A { get; set; }
 public List<B> B { get; set; }
 public List<IBase> UnionAB => A.Union(B).ToList();
}
```

In `DTO` i get error:

> `List<A>` Does not contain a definition for 'UNION' and the best
>   extension method overload `IQueryable.Union<B>(IQueryable<B>,
>   IEnumerable<B>)` requires a receiver of type `IQueryable<B>`

One clarification. Classes for union are much more than two. How better combine this classes? I don't want compare the classes. I want only `union all` like in `SQL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public List<IBase> UnionAB => A.Union<IBase>(B).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you that `Union`:

> requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable< B >'

so either you need to cast A to the `Ibase` type:

```
public List<IBase> UnionAB => A.Cast<IBase>().Union(B).ToList();
```

Or B:

```
public List<IBase> UnionAB => A.Union(B.Cast<IBase>()).ToList();
```

Or the third way is to specify the generic type parameter as `IBase` which would specify the resulting type and match your property: `public List<IBase> UnionAB`

```
public List<IBase> UnionAB => A.Union<IBase>(B).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
public List<IBase> UnionAB = new List<IBase>(A);
UnionAB.AddRange(B);
```